# Using C++, how can I move nodes backwards in a singly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void currentbac()
{
    if (current == first)
        cout << "This is the beginning of the list." << endl;
    else
    {
        list *previous;
        previous = first;
        while (previous->next != current)
        {
            previous = previous->next;
        }
        current = previous;
    }
}
```

This is the code I put for moving the "current" pointer backwards.
I 've initialized both current and first to null at the start of my code.

What I really want is to move the node through my list of nodes forward or backward.and then I want to insert a node whereever neccessary.
I know there are doubly linked lists but if someone can post the code for doubly linked list moving thats fine too.
But I wanted to know if you can move using a single linked list.

Also

```
void addmiddle()
{
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Current is invalid" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (current->next == NULL)
       addending();
    else
    {
        list *newlist;
        newlist=new list;
        cout << "Enter your name:" ;
        cin >> newlist->name;
        cout << "Enter your age:" ;
        cin >> newlist->age;
        cout << "Enter your height:" ;
        cin >> newlist->height;
        newlist->next=current->next;
        current->next=newlist;
    }
}
```

^ this is my code for adding a node in the middle of the list.I wanted to know how it works cos apparently im not able to move "Current"backwards.

Comment: Your question is unclear: you have `currentbac`, which looks correct, so you should be able to move forward and backward (albeit inefficiently). Also you seem to know how to insert a node (kind of). What more do you want?

Comment: I m not able to insert it inbetween TWO nodes.like when theres A and C,I want to insert B between A and C.I can only do this when I move "current" to A and then insert a node after that and then link it ,right?Im not able to move backwards for this

Comment: @Yuki not unless you have constructed a doubly linked list.

Comment: then what the hell...is there no way to insert nodes between two other nodes without it being a doubly linked list?

Comment: You want to insert after A. You can move `current` to A. You can insert after `current`. What's the problem?

Comment: how do I move current to A in that case is my question.

Comment: Using `currentbac`, that's how. What's the problem?

Comment: God...The Problem is that Im not able to move it at all.when I try and add nodes its either working at the beginning or the ending.But im not able to insert any INBETWEEN two nodes.And I dont know HOW?That looks like a problem doesnt it?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to do insertion (and talking about insertion) when you can't yet *move*. You have to solve the *moving* problem first. What happens when you try `currentbac`? (I suspect that your list has gotten corrupted, but we'll see.)